# EACCES: permission denied when trying to generate Angular component

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I try to generate a new component for my Angular app I immediately get a permission denied error but I do not know why. The command I try to run is

```
ng g component heroes
```

I have already tried chmod -R 755 on the project folder and all its contained files but this doesn't change the outcome unfortunately.

Here is the error message I get anytime I run the command.

```
EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/mynamehere/Documents/Web Dev/projects/angular/angular-tour-of-heroes/src/app/heroes'
[Finished in 3.5s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['ng', 'g', 'component', 'heroes']]
[dir: /Users/evanjameson/Documents/Web Dev/projects/angular/angular-tour-of-heroes]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/smlnj/bin]
```

This is from the AngularCLI package within sublime. When I run the same command in a terminal I get the same error message.

Comment: Try Running sublime with sudo or ng with sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `chmod 777` (instead of `755`) and look at the owner of the files that get generated. Probably sublime is running under different uid than you

Comment: This fixed it! Sublime was able to run the command as well! Whats significant about 777 instead of 755?

Comment: 777 allows everybody to write to the directory - and **generally** is not a safe option. What I was suggesting was *after* you set to 777, you will see who is the owner of the file. That's probably the account that sublime is running under. Then you may decide what to do - maybe `chown` the directory to that account, or chown the group and set permissions to 775... Several options, depending on your situation - but **don't** leave the permissions as 777; it was just a troubleshooting step!

Comment: Heres the permissions after chmod 777

"drwxrwxr-x   16 root  staff     512 May  3 17:50 src"

I switched It to 775 and it still worked, that should be ok right?